# Run protractor on live-server via grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, protractor

I am trying to run my portractor tests on live-server via one grunt task.
I have installed live-server (https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server) and grunt-execute. With grunt execute I managed to start live-server with a grunt command in 2 steps:

1st I created a node script (liveServer.js)

```
var liveServer = require("live-server");

var params = {
    port: 8080,
    host: "localhost",
    open: true,
    wait: 1000
};
liveServer.start(params);
```

2nd I created a task in my grunt file to start the script:
(in grunt.initConfig)

```
execute: {
    liveserver: {
        src: ['liveServer.js']
    },
}
```

and registered a command to trigger it:

```
grunt.registerTask('live', [
    'execute:liveserver'
]);
```

Now if I run "grunt live" in my commandline live-server starts, opens a browser, and I can browse my application.

I also created a protractor task in my grunt file, which works just fine as well.
(in grunt.initConfig)

```
protractor: {
    options: {
        keepAlive: false,
        noColor: false
    },
    e2e: {
        options: {
            configFile: 'protractor.conf.js',
        }
    }
},
```

If I trigger it with a registered task the protractor tests run just fine, only I have to make sure live-server is running first.
So ofcourse I want to combine the two in one command that starts live-server and then runs my protractor tests.
So I tried:

```
grunt.registerTask('runProtractor', [
    'execute:liveserver',
    'protractor'
]);
```

But unfortunately this does not work, live-server starts and then ... nothing happens, the protractor tests aren't run. I tried changing some of the live-server parameters such as open and wait, but without any luck. There are no error messages either.

As I said before separately the tasks work both fine (with two command windows, first start live-server in one and then protractor in the other)

Does anybody have a clue why my does not continue after the live-server has started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution of live-server blocks all subsequent tasks, since it doesn't "finish", i.e. to grunt the task is still running, which is why it won't proceed to the next task. You can use [grunt-concurrent](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent) to run tasks in parallel.

Comment: Thank you Camille!, I got it working with grunt-concurrent.